# How to extract the href attribute after a particular th in the wikipage infobox through Selenium or lxml using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, lxml, webdriverwait

The problem I have is to get the href of a particular cell in the infobox on a wikipage (Please see the image below). Specifically, I would like to get the href of the 3M's official website after the table's row header of "Website". The source code is highlighted in the image. (This wiki page format is pretty regular for most firms' wiki pages. I further plan to get websites for many firms, so it's not just to collect this one..)

The things I have tried but don't work:

```
# selenium:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='infoboxvcard']/tr[th/text()='Website']").get_attribute("href") 
# lxml:
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3M"
req = requests.get(url)
store = etree.fromstring(req.text)
output = store.xpath("//table[@class='infobox vcard']/tr[th/text()='Website']/td")
```

Code that works for a particular firm:

```
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3M")
website = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[17]/td/span/a").get_attribute("href")
```

However, since not all firms have the same number of rows, this code would not work when I loop over hundreds of firms.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3M

Screenshot from 3m wiki page:

[image: screenshot from 3m wiki page]

Comment: So you are looking for a more robust xpath?

Comment: @MosheSlavin yes. I want to put this xpath in a loop so it would work for many firm’s wikipage. The one works won’t work for this firm: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbott_Laboratories

Comment: So has the xpath in the answer helped?

Comment: @MosheSlavin yep! It works except wiki has a different structure. But that’s pretty solvable! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the *href* attribute of 3M's official website from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3M) *Selenium* itself would be sufficient and you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired element to be visible and you can use the following solution:

```
website = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//th[@scope='row' and text()='Website']//following::td[1]/span/a[@class='external text']"))).get_attribute("href")
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Your solution is also pretty cool!!! As Moshe Slavin's solution, it works pretty well except wiki has a different structure. But that’s pretty solvable! Thanks so much!

Comment: @QiaoWang Perhaps my answer was based on your verbatim _after the table's row header of "Website"_ :)

Comment: yeah... you’re right. “Website” is still the key here. it’s only that for some firms they don’t have a (span) after the (tr), so I just need to manipulate both your and Moshe’s codes a little bit. The imports you mentioned are pretty cool! Can be used for other similar problems!

Comment: I don't think you have to alter anything within my answer and it should work out of the box.

Comment: The issue I met is this part “td[1]/span/a”. For some firms it is just “td[1]/a”. In that case I need to manipulate a little bit. Sorry for my typo in last comment. You’re correct... i specially asked “after xxx”. Your code is the most direct one.

Comment: Your answer is better practice in selenium using `WebDriverWait`! +1, yet I like my XPATH better... what do you think?

Comment: @MosheSlavin `link_text` as **`3M.com`** will be native to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3M` but OP seems to be looking for a generic solution. `xpath` as **`//*[@class="url"]/a`** looks good enough but OP again seems to be specifically looking for _after the table's row header of "Website"_ which seems not within the initial viewport, so for a safer bet you need _WebDriverWait_.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more robust xpath:

```
website = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="url"]/a').get_attribute("href")
```

If you know the text you can use:

```
website = driver.find_element_by_link_text('3M.com').get_attribute("href")
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do you can store all link_text in excel sheet and fetch the string from excel and assign in a variable like I have assign for an example.Then use my below code it should work.

```
wb_link_text="3M.com"
wb_ele_href =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()[contains(.,'" + wb_link_text +"')]]").get_attribute("href")
print(wb_ele_href)
```

Let me know if that helps.